# How to send custom fields from Logback to Azure / AppInsights

Tags: java, azure, logging, logback

I'm using Logback with StructuredArguments to include custom fields in logged entries.

like so:

```
log.info("message", StructuredArguments.entries(Map.of("testKey", "testValue")));
```

How can I send these fields to Azure Appinsights ?

I see these messages in `traces` table but arguments from map are not included.

Comment: is spring sleuth with MDC and custom dimension an option? it will handle the propagation of those fields to underlying services too

Answer (score 0):

### Add dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
    <version>6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

### Then Configure Logback to use the Logstash appender by adding the following configuration to your logback.xml file

```
<appender name="logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>localhost:5044</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <customFields>{"ai.cloud.roleInstance": "your-instance-name"}</customFields>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
</root>
```

### and finally Use StructuredArguments in your Logback logs

```
log.info("message", StructuredArguments.entries(Map.of("testKey", "testValue")));
```

### Now Restart your application and Logstash